# how to link third-party static library to mysql-server 8.0 using cmake (got error:recompile with -fPIC)

Tags: c++, mysql, gcc, cmake

I'm modifying mysql-server 8.0 source code (development source tree) using a static third-party library called libfstack (whose file name is libfstack.a.1.21). But as a beginner of CMake, I cannot link the third-party library to the mysql project correctly.
Please let me know if you have any idea. Thanks!

This is the error message I got after executing `make`.

```
[ 67%] Built target clientlib_objlib
Scanning dependencies of target clientlib
[ 67%] Linking CXX static library ../archive_output_directory/libclientlib.a
[ 67%] Built target clientlib
Scanning dependencies of target libmysql
[ 67%] Building C object libmysql/CMakeFiles/libmysql.dir/libmysql_dummy.c.o
[ 67%] Linking CXX shared library ../library_output_directory/libmysqlclient.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfstack/libfstack.a.1.21(libfstack.ro): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `pcurthread' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfstack/libfstack.a.1.21(ff_dpdk_pcap.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `seq' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/librte_bus_dpaa.a(dpaa_bus.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against symbol `per_lcore_dpaa_io' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/librte_bus_dpaa.a(bman.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `per_lcore_bman_affine_portal' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/librte_bus_dpaa.a(bman_driver.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `bmfd' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/librte_bus_dpaa.a(qman.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `per_lcore_qman_affine_portal' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/librte_bus_dpaa.a(qman_driver.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `qmfd' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/librte_bus_fslmc.a(dpaa2_hw_dpio.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against symbol `per_lcore__dpaa2_io' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/librte_bus_vdev.a(vdev.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `per_lcore__thread_id.5396' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/librte_eal.a(eal_thread.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `per_lcore__thread_id.8400' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/librte_eal.a(eal_vfio.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `per_lcore__thread_id.8947' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/librte_eal.a(eal_interrupts.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `per_lcore__epfd' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/librte_eal.a(eal_common_log.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `per_lcore_log_cur_msg' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/librte_eal.a(eal_common_errno.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `per_lcore_retval.4583' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/librte_pmd_dpaa_sec.a(dpaa_sec.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `dpaa_sec_op_nb' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

I modified source code file mysql_socket.h, mysqld.cc and socket_connection.cc. By searching these file names in all project files (especially in xxx/CmakeLists.txt), I got that they are only related to target sql_main and vio. So I did following cmake configuration modifications.
By the way, I set the system env variable CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS to "-fPIC -shared" and built the libstack.a.1.21 with these flags.
I did everything I could, but still got stuck to the error mentioned above.

Following is the configuration I added in the sql/CMakeLists.txt.
PS: I built a simple helloworld program using cmake successfully, so I'm sure all necessary libraries are listed here.

```
set_property(TARGET sql_main PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
set_property(TARGET sql_main PROPERTY BUILD_SHARED_LIBS true)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/include)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/include/dpdk)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(sql_main /usr/local/lib/libfstack/libfstack.a.1.21)
file(GLOB LIBOTHERS "/usr/local/lib/*.a")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(sql_main -Wl,--whole-archive ${LIBOTHERST} -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(sql_main -lrt)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(sql_main -lm)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(sql_main -ldl)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(sql_main -lcrypto)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(sql_main -lpthread)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(sql_main -lnuma)
```

Following is the configuration I added in the vio/CMakeLists.txt.

```
set_property(TARGET vio PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
set_property(TARGET vio PROPERTY BUILD_SHARED_LIBS true)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/include)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/include/dpdk)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(vio /usr/local/lib/libfstack/libfstack.a.1.21)
file(GLOB LIBOTHERST "/usr/local/lib/*.a")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(vio -Wl,--whole-archive ${LIBOTHERST} -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(vio -lrt)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(vio -lm)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(vio -ldl)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(vio -lcrypto)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(vio -lpthread)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(vio -lnuma)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `libfstack` wasn't compiled with `-fPIC` enabled and you're trying to link it into a shared library. You wrote that you set `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` to `-fPIC -shared` when recompiling `libfstack`, but I suspect that added `-shared` caused that recompilation to only build the shared version of the library, leaving the old `libfstack.a.1.21` as it was before.

Alternatively, if you don't want to recompile `libfstack` you need to ensure that `mysql-server` doesn't build shared libraries. Usually that can be done by using `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`, but seeing `set_property(TARGET vio PROPERTY BUILD_SHARED_LIBS true)` in the `CMakeLists.txt` you posted I'm afraid that mysql-server doesn't allow switching between static and shared builds out of the box. So you'd need to go in change it manually.

Comment: thanks a lot, i removed the -shared flag and the static library can be linked by a shared library.